# C#: Split a Single Annual Figure into Monthly amounts based on an arbitrary Y=f(X) formula

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, statistics, finance

I have an annual figure, let's say for purposes of this question that the figure is 100%.

What I would like to do is have C# split the 100% figure into a curved distribution of monthly percentages based on a specific formula `Y = f(X)`, that still add to 100.

This is likely primarily a math question - how could I accomplish this without manually keying in figures that add to 100?

Comment: Do you have a categorization of the seasonality (or whatever).  If it is flat, then each month will be 100.0 /12.0 (8.333).  If it's not flat, then you have to do the mathmatical equivalent of plotting the curve and reading the values at each month.  Say the graph is step-ish, in the 3 winter months, it's 20% of max, in spring, it's 60% of max, 100% in the summer and 60% in the fall.  Add them all up and normalize to a 100% sum (dividing each of those figures by 7.2 so that they all add up to 100%)

Comment: *"How could I accomplish this without manually keying in figures that add to 100?"* **You don't.** Every industry has it's own seasonal adjustments, so not only does the user have to select "Seasonal", they also have to select the industry. And you need to type in the 4 or 12 numbers for every industry that you want to support. Those numbers don't necessarily need to add up to 100. They can be normalized by the software.

Comment: @Flydog57 - Let's say the curve I want to "use" is X = Y(^2) + 3. What I'd like is to "insert" this formula into a method that distributes values into a 12-length array that add to 100. I'm currently looking at the Trapezoidal Intregation method. I can create an arbitrary curve that is representative of the business context easily, but I don't know how to normalize that area to a total of 100 with a finite number of datapoints.

Comment: @user3386109 - the exact Seasonal formula is irrelevant - we just need to apply a graphable curve formula to a distribution with a summation restriction

Comment: @Coruscate5: That's an unusual curve.  Generally X is along the horizontal axis, and functions are generally expressed as Y = _f_ (X) (or, more usually, Y = _f_ ( _t_ ) (where _t_ is time.  Just figure out what the values are per month (or per week, or per day or per hour).  Use the same kind of summing/dividing to normalize the results to 100% over the year

Comment: @Coruscate5 If your comment to Flydog57 is your real question, then you should post that as your question. And you already have the answer. Integrate, and normalize.

Comment: Correct on both points - it should have read y=f(x). Likely, my issue is that I've never done integration in C#, so that's likely what is tripping me here. I have sample code, but it doesn't work - is that helpful to post?

Comment: Seasonal adjustments aren't so crazy that they require trapezoidal integration. Nor are they accurate. If you have the annual figures, and the monthly figures from two different businesses in the same industry, you'll find the monthly figures are easily 20% off between the two businesses. So just sample the curve 360 times, add up 30 samples for each month, and then normalize the sums.

Comment: Integration (particularly of a discrete function like this) is just a summing of the values over time.  Computers and computer languages are really good at this: `var sum = 0.0; for (var i = 0; i <12; ++i) { sum += value[i]; }`.  The normalization is a similar for loop, that does a divsion.

Comment: Welp, the Trapezoidal integration works, but is completely unnecessary as noted and overly complex. Updated question for clarity. I will append the working snippet console app to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment as an answer.  The way to do this is to get the seasonality curve expressed over time.  Let's consider a simple case, where we the curve looks like a step-ish sine-ish curve.  We'll use a unit of "percentage of maximum value" to describe the curve.  Seasons will be 3 months long, so winter is Dec-Feb, spring is Mar-May, etc.

The curve looks like:

| Dec-Feb | Mar-May | Jun-Aug | Sep-Nov |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20% of Max | 60% of Max | 100% of Max | 60% of Max |

If you add those all up (for 12 months), you will get 720%, or 7.2.  So, the actual values you want to use are:

| Dec-Feb | Mar-May | Jun-Aug | Sep-Nov |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.78 (i.e., 20.0/7.2) | 8.33 (60.0/7.2) | 13.89 (100.0/7.2) | 8.33 (60.0/7.2) |

Checking this to make sure it's valid:

`2.78 * 3 + 8.33 * 6 + 13.89 *3 = 99.99` (or, just about 100)

---

Some working sample code for a C# console app using an arbitrary sinusoidal function that vaguely represents some early and late seasonality - MyFunction can be replaced with any function, including a stepwise one like above:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace Test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int months = 12;

        double[] scaleExpectations = new double[months];

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            scaleExpectations[i] = MyFunction(i);
        }

        double sum = scaleExpectations.Sum(); //this is the actual Integral of the series, since it is not a real curve

        double[] percents = new double[months];

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            percents[i] = Math.Round((scaleExpectations[i] * 100) / sum, 2);

            Console.WriteLine($"iteration {i} with value {percents[i]}");

            if (i == 11) // remove rounding error by altering last position
            {
                var error = 100 - percents.Sum();
                percents[i] = percents[i] + error;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(percents.Sum());

    }

    public static double MyFunction(double input)
    {
        return .4 * Math.Sin(.5 * (input - 7.5)) + .9;
    }
}
}
```